# Failed to execute goal on project sip-servlets-core-api

Tags: maven, tomcat, sip-server, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am trying to make an SIP servlet, after a lot of research on Session Initiation Protocal(SIP) servlets I am now using mobicent's sip servlet project with TOMCAT...!

I am following [this](http://www.mobicents.org/installation-tomcat.html) guide to get my goal, the issue is that when I am trying to run the command **mvn clean install** in the project directory, it starts download the dependencies but suddenly it encounters by an error

Here's the error log,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sip-servlets-core-api: Could not resol
ve dependencies for project org.mobicents.servlet.sip:sip-servlets-core-api:jar:
1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobice
nts-jain-sip-ext:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mo
bicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer ar
tifact org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT from/to C
odehaus Snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): snapshots.reposito
ry.codehaus.org: Unknown host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project sip-servlets-core-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.
mobicents.servlet.sip:sip-servlets-core-api:jar:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collec
t dependencies at org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:jar:1.1-SNAPSHO
T
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project org.mobicents.servlet.sip:sip-servlets-core-api:ja
r:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobi
cents-jain-sip-ext:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed t
o collect dependencies at org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:jar:1.1
-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDe
pendencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
read artifact descriptor for org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:jar:
1.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCa
chedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifa
ctDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(D
efaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDe
pendencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
transfer artifact org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:pom:1.1-SNAPSHO
T from/to Codehaus Snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): snapsho
ts.repository.codehaus.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
acts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
act(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tran
sfer artifact org.mobicents.javax.sip:mobicents-jain-sip-ext:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT fr
om/to Codehaus Snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): snapshots.r
epository.codehaus.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transfer
Failed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunne
r.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Runn
ableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExe
cutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(Basic
RepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownl
oads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: snapshots.repository.
codehaus.org
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:11
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run
(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTran
sporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTranspor
ter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRu
nner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunne
r.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: snapshots.repository.codehaus.org
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.SystemDefa
ultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClient
ConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHtt
pClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Proto
colExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Retry
Exec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Redir
ectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Internal
HttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Closeabl
eHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute
(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
        ... 50 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sip-servlets-core-api
```

And below is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
            <artifactId>mobicents</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mobicents</groupId>
            <version>1.27-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.servlet.sip</groupId>
    <artifactId>sip-servlets-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>  
    <name>Mobicents Sip Servlets</name>
    <url>http://www.mobicents.org/products_sip_servlets.html</url>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>Hudson</system>
        <url>https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/MobicentsSipServlets/</url>
    </ciManagement>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>jean.deruelle</id>
            <name>Jean Deruelle</name>
            <email>jean.deruelle@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>JBoss/Red Hat</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.redhat.com/</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>Project Lead</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+1</timezone>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>vralev</id>
            <name>Vladimir Ralev</name>
            <email>vladimir.ralev@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>JBoss/Red Hat</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.redhat.com/</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>Active Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+1</timezone>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>baranowb</id>
            <name>Bartosz Baranowski</name>
            <email>baranowb@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>JBoss/Red Hat</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.redhat.com/</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+1</timezone>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>mranga</id>
            <name>Neo Ranga</name>
            <email>mranga@dev.java.net</email>
            <roles>
                <role>Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>-5</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE</name>
            <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/servers/sip-servlets</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/servers/sip-servlets</developerConnection>
        <url>http://code.google.com/p/mobicents/source/browse/trunk/servers/sip-servlets</url>
    </scm>
    <modules>
        <module>sip-servlets-bootstrap</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-spec</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-client</module>        
        <module>sip-servlets-jruby</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-core-api</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-impl</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-application-router</module>
        <module>sip-servlets-annotations</module>       
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <mobicents.tools.mavenplugin.eclipse.version>1.0.0.FINAL</mobicents.tools.mavenplugin.eclipse.version>
        <mobicents.cluster.version>1.12</mobicents.cluster.version>
        <mobicents.balancer.version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</mobicents.balancer.version>
        <mobicents.jain.sip.ha.version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</mobicents.jain.sip.ha.version>
        <mobicents.jain.sip.ext.version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</mobicents.jain.sip.ext.version>       
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
            <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                        <tagBase>
                                https://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/tags/servers/sip-servlets/
                        </tagBase>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <g />
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-6</version>                                   
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mobicents.tools</groupId>
                <version>${mobicents.tools.mavenplugin.eclipse.version}</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions />
                <configuration>             
                    <!--generateProjectsForModules>true</generateProjectsForModules-->  
                    <resolveTransitiveDependencies>true</resolveTransitiveDependencies>
                    <eclipseProjectName>sip-servlets-bootstrap</eclipseProjectName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>      
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>           
            <id>site</id>       
            <build>         
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>site</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy verbose="true" file="${project.build.directory}/site/index.html" tofile="${project.build.directory}/site/products_sip_servlets.html" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                            <tagBase>https://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/tags/servers/sip-servlets
                            </tagBase>
                            <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>release</id>
            <modules>
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>              
                <module>sip-servlets-tomcat-jboss4</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-metadata</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jruby</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-deployer</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-ha-server-cache</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5</module>            
                <module>sip-servlets-management</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-examples</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-test-suite</module>
                <module>docs</module>               
            </modules>
            <properties>
                 <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>tomcat</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>           
            <modules>       
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>                      
                <module>sip-servlets-tomcat-jboss4</module>             
            </modules>  
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>     
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>jboss</id>
            <modules>               
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>              
                <module>sip-servlets-tomcat-jboss4</module>             
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>         
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>jboss-5</id>            
            <modules>       
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>              
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-metadata</module>   
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-deployer</module>                   
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-ha-server-cache</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5</module>                
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>         
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>tomcat-distro</id>          
            <modules>               
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>              
                <module>sip-servlets-tomcat-jboss4</module>             
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>         
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>jboss-distro</id>
            <modules>       
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>                      
                <module>sip-servlets-tomcat-jboss4</module>             
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>         
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>jboss-5-distro</id>         
            <modules>
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina</module>              
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-metadata</module>   
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-deployer</module>                   
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5-ha-server-cache</module>
                <module>sip-servlets-jboss5</module>                
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>6.0.35</tomcat.version> 
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>         
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>tomcat-7</id>           
            <modules>
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina-7</module>            
                <module>tomcat-7</module>
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>7.0.26</tomcat.version>
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat-7-distro</id>
            <modules>
                <module>sip-servlets-catalina-7</module>            
                <module>tomcat-7</module>
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <tomcat.version>7.0.26</tomcat.version>
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>as7</id>
            <modules>
                <module>sip-servlets-as7</module>
            </modules>
            <properties>
                <!-- keep in sync with jboss-as/pom.xml -->
                <!-- <version.org.jboss.web>7.0.10.Final</version.org.jboss.web> -->
                <version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec>1.0.0.Final</version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- j2ee dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </profile>
        <profile>           
            <id>docs</id>
            <modules>
                <module>docs</module>               
            </modules>          
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <!-- repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-3rd-party-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss ThirdParty Releases Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-3rd-party-upload-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss ThirdParty Upload Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-upload</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>java.net-Public</id>
        <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
        <!--url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url-->
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JbossRepository</id>
            <name>Jboss Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>backup.repository.jboss.org</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository Backup</name>
            <url>http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <!--repository>
            <id>jboss-snapshots</id>
            <name>JBoss Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository-->
    </repositories>
</project>
```

If you have a better way to work SIP server, please tell me. Your Suggestions and help is very very important...!

Thanks in Advance.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.7.0 is very old, please use https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets instead. why do you try to recompile the project instead of using the pre-built binaries at https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/releases ?

Comment: Now, I implemented the precompiled binaries, but I am unable to import the code in eclipse

Comment: Please suggest me a way for that

Comment: run mvn eclipse:eclipse -P as7, as8, tomcat-7, tomcat-8 at the root.

Comment: Hi bro, now I am getting SipFactory is not bound in this context...!

Comment: Thanks bro, but I have resolved the bug....! **SIP** is really interesting for me

Comment: Glad to hear that, next step is to contribute ? :D